# Geometry nodes - Object info: "Does contain object" - return as boolean

Tags: geometry-nodes

Can I get bool value from the question "does node **object info** contain object right now?" somehow? (or collection info node)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a more simple way to get boolean value, by using scale
It works fine even with an empty input.
You can also use absolute node from vector math to handle negative-scale-objects
[image]

Answer (score 8):

With Blender V3.1+ you can use the [Domain Size](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/domain_size.html) node in that way :

[image]

The output of the *Math* node can be used as a boolean since it will return 0 if there a no evaluated instances in the *Object Info* node. You don't even need the *Math* node since the instance count will evaluate to True for values > 0.

With Blender 3.0 I don't know of a very straightforward way. I'll assume the object contains some geometry with at least 2 vertices. You can use the [Attribute Statistic](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_statistic.html) node :

[image]

The output of pretty much any socket of the node will evaluate to True if there are at least 2 vertices in the mesh.

Answer (score 3):

**Note: use Gorgious' solution, unless you really need Blender 3.0**

In Blender 3.0 You can pass any non-zero value for a point, then use any of the 5 first outputs of the *Attribute Statistic* node:

[image]

This is only a slight improvement from Gorgious' answer, as it works for a single vertex as well. However, you could just use *Scale* and assume no object has scale = 0;0;0:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to check if the input field of my geometry node contained any object...
Using the logic from the previous answers, I came up with something similar:

[image: Using Boundig Box]

If there is no object selected, then the size of the bounding box will equal zero.
In my case, I'm using the result for a switch node. If the result is zero (there is no selected object in the input field) I'm adding a "purple mesh", so the user can see it in the viewport.