# How I can tell if an input of kind object or material is empty?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to be able to tell if an input for a geometry node is empty or not.

So far I found I can check if an object that is set from an input is empty or not like this.

[image]

This feels like a hack and I wonder if there is a proper way for doing this.

Also I will like to check if a material is empty or not when it comes from an input, I tried comparing the input material with an empty one but it seems like the result can't be used in a switch node

[image]

Comment: 1) About testing empty geometry input: as a hack, I am testing the *Scale* socket to save the computation time of the *Bounding Box* node. For empty input geometry parameter, I find that the *Scale* is (0,0,0). 2) About testing material, may I suggest to read this post: [Is there a way to connect a field Boolean output to a geometry switch node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296335/is-there-a-way-to-connect-a-field-boolean-output-to-a-geometry-switch-node) ?

Comment: Thank you! Using the scale is better than the Bounding Box

Comment: Object: [Geometry nodes - Object info: "Does contain object" - return as boolean](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/254092/60486).

Comment: What's left is the green geometry input. You can use "domain size" to check if there's any element of any type (quite a lot of nodes...)